# How do I group by and calculate aggregate functions on DataTable (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by, average

From a given DataTable e.g.

```
Val1     Val2     Col1     Col2
10        100      A        B
20        200      A        B
30        300      C        C
40        400      C        C
```

I would like to create a different data table with aggregation functions and group by just like the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT MIN(Val1), MAX(Val2), AVG(Val1), AVG(Val2), StdDev(Val1) From DataTable GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

Please note that StdDev is a function that I need to probably develop myself, while Max, Min, Average are probably already existing in Linq

How to do it in C#? 
Is it possible in Linq?
Do you know any extensions / libraries that allow to do that?

I was looking for other questions but they usually relate to selecting a Minimum value (but not as aggregate function, but by selecting the first value after ordering) or focus on grouping.

Comment: @Downvoter - leave a comment when down vote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Something like this

```
var groupedData = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
              group row by new {Col1=row["Col1"].ToString(), Col2=row["Col2"].ToString()} into g
              select new
              {
                    Col1 = g.Key.Col1,
                    Col2 = g.Key.Col2,
                    MinVal1 = g.Min(x => x.Field<decimal>("Val1")),
                    MaxVal2 = g.Max(x => x.Field<decimal>("Val2")),
                    MinVal1 = g.Min(x => x.Field<decimal>("Val1")),
                    AvgVal1 = g.Average(x => x.Field<decimal>("Val1")),
                    AvgVal2 = g.Average(x => x.Field<decimal>("Val2"))

              };

foreach (var group in groupedData )
{

}
```